# Develop app so two mobile phones can directly communicate using their network sensor

Tags: networking, telephony, mobile-phones, cellular-network

Mobile phones are like radios which listen/broadcast on their bands.  A mobile phone can connect to a base station and then to another mobile phone.  Since the mobile phone has a range of 5 km, I would like to create an app that allows two devices to connect to each other without a base station.

Can anyone provide a reference to a book, online tutorial, website.. anything?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which phones do you want to use?  Do you have a language preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current mobile phones, the radio used to communicate with the phone network is not under the direct control of the main CPU, where your application runs.  It is controlled by a separate *baseband processor*, and the software on this is not typically user-updateable (often, it is not even updateable by the manufacturer of the phone!).